# Rails Enum: overriding getter to always compare with symbols instead of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking at ActiveRecord's Enum [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), I find it inconsistent that sometimes I'm allowed to use symbols and sometimes I'm required to use only strings.

From the docs, you can query using symbols:

```
Conversation.where(status: [:active, :archived])
Conversation.where.not(status: :active)
```

But you can't compare using symbols:

```
conversation = Conversation.new(status: :active)
conversation.status # "active"
conversation.status == :active # false
```

And you can set the status using a symbol, but reading it back will return a string, so you must always use strings to compare:

```
conversation.status = :active # :active
conversation.status # "active"
```

My point is: I wished to use only symbols, because performance, and it feels more idiomatic to me. If enums are defined using symbols, and can be queried using symbols, why should I be forced (and have to remember!) to use strings when comparing something like `conversation.status == "active"` ?

My idea is to override getter:

```
def status
  super.try(:to_sym)
end
```

This way, I can always use symbols. Any reasonable reason for not doing this?

Comment: You cant enum is being saved as int/string. You can use `conversation.active?` or `conversation.archived?`

Answer (score 1):

> But you can't compare using symbols:

```
conversation = Conversation.new(status: :active)
conversation.status # "active"
conversation.status == :active # false
```

You dont need to compare with symbols:

```
conversation.active? # true
```

> Any reasonable reason for not doing this?

Yes, you should use the library methods and modules instead of writing you own untested and excess code.

Answer (score 1):

No need to compare enum with string or integer. [DOC Link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

```
conversation = Conversation.new(status: :active)
conversation.active? #true/false
```